# Help me identify a 'techy' sans-serif typeface used in a lost project

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

I lost a bunch of project files with fonts in tow. I cannot identify/find this typeface anywhere. I know it only comes in 2 weights.

- The font is unedited.
- There are 2 weights: Bold and Thin

I used the usual avenues for identification already, including WhatTheFont! / Identifont / What Font is

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Christopher Dowding! We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And the winner is...

**V.GER Grotesque**

https://www.behance.net/gallery/vger-grotesque/6636573

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a quick few searches, I'm almost certain that this font is [Shearman-Std](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/uff/shearman-std/bold/) but someone has edited the glyphs slightly for this project, perhaps to avoid copyright.

[image: What the Font]

If you look and see, even the E has the corner cut of the same, but the letter in your piece has been flipped and edited slightly. I'm almost certain about this, but if anyone disagrees with my finding please let me know.

Comment: Looking at the rounded corners from the Letters "Y" and "O", the shape of the "T" , width of "I" and other refinements on "H","E","A","N" + horizontal proportions, I wouldn't really say that's matching, but it could surely be...

Comment: Well, it's definitely not altered as I used it. I lost the files when I was robbed of my machine earlier in the week, it was the only project not in the cloud, unfortunately. :( This has been a difficult round of font finding I must say!